# Как получить координаты по заданному адресу?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Доброго времени суток.

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    var myPlacemark,
        myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.753994, 37.622093],
            zoom: 9,
            controls: ['zoomControl', 'geolocationControl',  'fullscreenControl', 'routeButtonControl']
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        });

var suggestView1 = new ymaps.SuggestView('suggest1'); //база адресов

}


 $("#suggest1").change(function(){
var t=$("#suggest1").val(); //получаем адрес 

//определяем координаты по адресу: Россия, Москва, Свободный проспект, 1Б 
ymaps.geocode(t,{results:1}).then(
function(res){  var MyGeoObj = res.geoObjects.get(0);
//извлечение координат
document.getElementById('one').value = MyGeoObj.geometry.getCoordinates();

});

        });
})
```

В общем я получаю координаты
но они не верные
не выходит получить достоверные координаты
Выручайте пожалуйста

Comment: Что значит неверные?

Comment: когда начинаю вводить адрес то дальше выбираю из выпадающего списка
Россия, Москва, Свободный проспект, 1Б - такой допустим
56.02345 92.828973 и такие координаты я получаю
но это даже не Москва а Красноярск

Comment: Увеличьте значение results, там скорее всего много чего вам приходит, в том числе и первым Красноярск